# Given $(A-I)^2 = 0$, can we say det$(A)=1$ and tr$(A)=n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, trace

> Given $(A-I)^2 = 0$, can we say det$(A)=1$ and tr$(A)=n$?

First I showed when $A$ is two by two, this is true. Since $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 2$ and $\lambda_1 \lambda_2=1$, then from substitution $\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{\lambda_2}$, this gives $(\lambda_2-1)^2 = 1$, and therefore $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 1$.

I tried the case when $A$ is $3\times 3$ by first fixing the third eigenvalue and solve for the other two, and it also worked. How would I approach such problem when $A$ is $n\times n$.

Comment: We have $A^2-2A+I=0$, which becomes $A(2I-A)=I$, so at least $\det(A)\neq0$.

Comment: You may assume $A$ is in Jordan form without losing anything

Comment: @WillJagy Why are you allowed to assume Jordan form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue (in the complex numbers) of $A$; then $Av=\lambda v$ for some $v\ne0$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$; therefore
$$
(A-I)v=(\lambda-1)v
$$
and
$$
0=(A-I)^2v=(A-I)(\lambda-1)v=(\lambda-1)^2v
$$
Therefore $(\lambda-1)^2=0$ and so $\lambda=1$. Thus $A$ has just the eigenvalue $1$, with algebraic multiplicity $n$.

The determinant of $A$ is the product of the eigenvalues and the trace their sum (counted with their multiplicity).

Comment: Why does that imply 1 is only eigenvalue rather than just a multiplicity of 2?

Answer (score 0):

$(t-1)^2=0$ is anihilating polynomial which suggests two possibilities of the minimal polynomial i.e. $(t-1)=0$ or $(t-1)^2=0$. In either case, the only eigenvalue is $1$. Now, trace(A)$=\sum_{i=0}^{n}t_i$

Comment: Does this imply 1 is the only eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes as minimal polynomial contains all eigenvalues.

Comment: So, as soon as you see a matrix polynomial equal to zero, you know that the matrix has at most a number of eigenvalues equal to the degree of the polynomial (up to multiplicity), right?

Comment: Not exactly like that. But if it is a minimal polynomial then the answer is YES.

Comment: You know it will be multiple of the minimal polynomial though, right?  And, if so, does that not imply what I said?  Is there some caveat I'm missing?

Comment: yes it is muptiple of minimal polynomial and thus called an anihilating polynomial. For example $(t-k)(t-1)=0, k\ne 1\in \mathbb R$ is anihilating polynomial of identity matrix $I$ but $k$ doesn't belong to the set of its eigenvalues.